# Negative Lookahead, match every line except "fname lname" regular expression

Tags: regex

I have multiple lines of text and I want to run regex on each line to find matches for

```
^.*(?!fname lname)\b([A-Za-z'$]+ [A-Za-z'$]+) is present
```

it works seamlessly, scanning lines that don't have the input name, with the example of the following lines:

- fname lname is present
- and fname lname is present
- or fname lname is present
- blah blah fname lname is present
- abcd efgh fname lname is present

link: https://regex101.com/r/lvPpbL/1

however for names that has apostrophes, it breaks.

```
^.*(?!fn'ame ln'ame)\b([A-Za-z'$]+ [A-Za-z'$]+) is present
```

lines:

- fn'ame ln'ame is present
- and fn'ame ln'ame is present
- or fn'ame ln'ame is present
- blah blah fn'ame ln'ame is present
- abcd efgh fn'ame ln'ame is present

link: https://regex101.com/r/YSReTt/1

how can I make it work for names with apostrophes

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Why not just use `fname lname is present` literally? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: it's a different sentence and I'm trying to match each line that doesn't have the fname lname. for a 1000+ text.@ggorlen

Comment: where can I input the name @Mandy8055

Comment: yes, Exactly! @Mandy8055 , it's working in the first link
However, I'm having issues right now with names that include apostrophes.

Comment: I updated your [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/lvPpbL/2). Please check it. If you just want to match all the Strings that will not match fname and lname; you can use [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/lvPpbL/4) regex which is much more efficient and legible.

Comment: you need to escape the single quote when you use it in the lookahead like you are `\'`  https://regex101.com/r/YSReTt/5

Comment: You do realize that `$` within `[]` is just a dollar sign and not end-of-string or end-of-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it "seems" to work for the first examples is because you match `is present` right after `fname lname`

If you add a word between, like `fname lname test is present` you can see that it [does not work anymore](https://regex101.com/r/GHYBy3/1)

In the second example it becomes clear why it does not work. It does not have an extra "word" in between, but the word boundary `\b` DOES match between the apostrophe and the a in `ln'ame`

In both parts is should match at least `[A-Za-z'$]+ [A-Za-z'$]+` and then  `is present`

It can not do that in the first examples, but it can do that in the second examples as the word boundary matches and will match `ame ln'ame` followed by  `is present`

The reason for this behaviour is due to backtracking caused by using `.*` in the pattern. It will first match until the end of the line, and then asserts that what is on the right is not `fn'ame ln'ame`. This is true, as it is at the end of the string.

Then the pattern gives up matches until it can fit the rest of the pattern.

You can fix your pattern by adding the `.*` in the lookahead instead. If you want to match both variants, you could make the `'` optional using `'?`

```
^(?!.*fn'?ame ln'?ame)[A-Za-z'$]+(?: [A-Za-z'$]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9FrZI/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it's working, and thank you for the explanation. it makes sense now